How to get true superuser privileges on Windows 11?
Like the title says. Since admin is now the Windows 11 version of power user, how can I make changes the system does not want to allow? I used to run as NT authority/trusted installer but even that is hit and miss in the recent builds of Windows. I don't care if I end up breaking something, I just want to be able to make changes to my own system.
And since someone will probably ask, this is my SolidWorks workstation. It sounds like a jet fighter taking off. I want to destroy the waasmedic and updateorchestrator so it will stop turning updates back on and waking the PC (and me) in the middle of the night.

At worst you should see these services peaking occasionally, when patches are installing. Perhaps you should be looking to adjust your system's thermal modes, using Active Hours, or the other built-in and supported methods for controlling when updates install.

@Ramhound You can run Powershell scripts as the NT Authority\System user simply by having them run as a child process of a privileged process - this is the default when you run scripts remotely in Azure / how I run OS provisioning scripts for new Virtual Machines.

@Ramhound No, that's a massive oversimplification. Even putting SYSTEM aside, there are many groups with predefined access that a user can be part of – Power Users, Backup Operators, Account Operators, etc. (A user who's a member of Backup Operators has the privilege to bypass file permissions, for example, without actually being an Administrator.)

You need to define what you mean by "SuperUser" the simple definition: "One user that can do everything" doesn't exist by default in Windows, because the various security checks are split across several permissions:
There are two SIDs:

NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM - Which passes "most" security checks.
BUILTIN\Administrators - Often used for security checks for administrative functions (again passes "most" checks).

Both of these SID's are in the ACL for the LocalSystem account, hence that account has very high privileges (in addition to having access to some protected areas of the registry).
However most of the critical files on the file-system are owned by the account TrustedInstaller. As an administrator, the system will allow you to take ownership of files (allowing you to write to them) however by default administrative (and system) users are not granted the ability to write to critical system files (only TrustedInstaller can do that), without taking ownership of them first.

The "true" superuser would be code running in Kernel space, it is possible to write code that runs in kernel space (Device Drivers, CrowdStrike, some Anti-Cheat software) however at that point your are beyond all protections that the OS provides - most mistakes results in an instant blue screen of death, read: you probably don't want to go down that path.
